# highcharts stacked column overlaps when toggling the legends visibility

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I've created a stacked column chart using highchart it works fine. but when I toggle the visibility of a particular legend the column overlaps each other.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', { 
"chart": {
    "type": "column",
    "zoomType": "x",
    "panning": true,
    "panKey": "shift",
    "shadow": true,
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "RotisSemiSans"
    }
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "subtitle": {},
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "datetime"
  },
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "title": {
        "text": "some value"
      },
      "opposite": false,
      "type": "column"
    }
  ],
  "tooltip": {},
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "stacking": "normal"
    },
    "line": {
      "marker": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    },
    "area": {
      "marker": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    },
    "pointRange": 1
  },
  "legend": {
    "itemWidth": 150,
    "maxHeight": 65
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "series": [
    {
    }],
});
```

Tried setting stack name but that too didn't work. setting the **pointRange** doesn't work either.
[image]
[see it the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mithun146/y6ur217g/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of using `pointRange` is a good way of dealing with it, you just misplaced it a bit. You have:

```
"plotOptions": {
  "series": {
    "stacking": "normal"
  },
  // ...
  "pointRange": 1
},
```

Instead do ([JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/xvkz5Lja/)):

```
"plotOptions": {
  "series": {
    "stacking": "normal"
    "pointRange": 5 * 60 * 1000
  },
  // ...
},
```

My example above uses 5 minutes, since that appears to be your interval. I am unsure of why it fails in the first place, but this should resolve the overlapping issue.

Comment: great, thanks for the help. I wondering why it adjust/change the Xaxis data label when you toggle the legends visibility, by any chance this can be restrained?